# update not working in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Hi I have created an application for inventory management.

But when I do the update function, the flow was OK and no errors are found at runtime. But the table remains unchanged.

```
  conn = getConnection();
            preStmt = conn
                    .prepareStatement("UPDATE category SET name=? where id=?;");
            preStmt.setString(1, category.getCategoryName());
            preStmt.setInt(2, category.getCategoryId());
            preStmt.executeUpdate();
            closeDb();
```

Comment: Try to `System.out.println(preStmt.executeUpdate())` and let us know what the output. If output is 0 then there no update is happen

Comment: Do you have record in category where name is `category.getCategoryName()` and id is `category.getCategoryId()`?

Comment: @SMA id is category.getCategoryId() (primary key)

Comment: Do you have a record in DB already? Did you by default disabled autoCommit by any chance?

Comment: yes i have record in table. but i did not check auto commit.

Comment: That is the row count of update. That means 1 row is updated with the given id. So it's not clear why you are not getting the update in reflection. I think you are using some tools to database browsing  like - sqldeveloper or mysqlworkbench. If it is then try  to refresh the view. Hope it will help

Comment: @Razib i'm using mysql workbench.   i try refresh table , but not happening.

Comment: setAutoCommit(true) also not work? Try to Select the query with the the id that you given in your source cod. Sometimes mysql workbech shows limited for example 50 top rows only

Comment: What's the closeDB() doing, could you show this method code.

Comment: @sandeep closeDb just releasring connection 
`connection.close();`

Answer (score 1):

You should either finish the transaction:

```
conn.commit();
```

or set the atutocommit before creating the prepared statements:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Comment: not working
`conn = getConnection();
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
  preStmt = conn
    .prepareStatement("UPDATE category SET name=? where id=?;");
  preStmt.setString(1, category.getCategoryName());
  preStmt.setInt(2, category.getCategoryId());
  preStmt.executeUpdate();
  conn.commit();`

Comment: Could you show us the values of conn.isClosed() and con.isValid(0) just after calling conn = getConnection(); ? Could you make a select on this table with the values of name and id? could you show us also the description of the table? could you show us the return values of executeUpdate(...)?

Comment: `conn.isClosed--false`
`con.isValid--true`
`CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client `

Comment: we would need to know what preStmt.executeUpdate(); returns, the type of category.getCategoryId() (is it a Long?) and finally a select count on that table with the "where id=?" using your CategoryId.

Comment: id is int not float.
`ResultSet resultset = null;
  preStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM category WHERE id=?;");
  preStmt.setInt(1, id);
  resultset = preStmt.executeQuery();
  Category category = null;
  if (resultset.next()) {
   category = new Category();
   category.setCategoryId(resultset.getShort(1));
   category.setCategoryName(resultset.getString(2));
  }
  closeDb();`
i got category object when passing id.

Comment: Could you try to close the prepared statement after the commit?